# How to target <span> element after html tag?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How I can target first child of span after some html tag? My markup is is like this:

```
<div class="gad-help">
    <a href="#">AdWords vodič<br><span>osigurajte najbolje rezultate</span></a>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.gad-help span:nth-child(1) {
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid red;
        padding: 0px 10px;        
}
```

But it won't select it when I use `<br>` tag in front of  tag.

Comment: do you need to support older browser? (IE<9)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan, nope :)

Comment: You don’t target tags at all in CSS. CSS operates on the DOM, which contains elements. The concepts “after a tag” and “after an element” are completely different. You should formulate your question in terms of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `span:first-of-type` or `span:nth-of-type(1)` are what you're looking for. But note that they both will select the first `span` child element of their parents. in this case the anchor tag, not the `div` element.

Therefore if you want to target the first anchor tag, you should do that by `.glad-help > a:first-of-type` instead (or `:first-child` in this case).

Comment: Yes, I have to target first-of-type, not first-child. I'm only targeting two spans inside of div.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/zgdxb13r/)**

css

```
.gad-help a span:first-of-type {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Yes, :first-of-type work like a charm. Guess, I have to learn css pseudo classes better.